# Sorting a pageBlockTable on a VF page

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have created a Visualforce page. The page lists records from a Custom Object called "Training & Certification".  It looks like this...
[image]

As you can see in the Red Box, the list needs to be sorted in desending order, based on the "Course Code" field (which is a formula field if that matters).
I am hoping there is a simple way to do this.
Thanks
Shawn

Comment: is this a pageblock table, if so post your controller code, may be its as simple as adding an ORDER BY to your query

Comment: Where in the code would the Order By go? I am very new and just learning how to code so I apologize for my basic questions?

Answer (score 3):

Please see [ORDER BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) for specifics, but basically, somewhere in your code, you have a line of code that probably looks like:

```
List<Training_Certification__c> trainCertRecords = 
    [SELECT Id, Name, Course_Level__c, Course_Description__c 
     FROM Training_Certification__c];
```

In which case, the easiest way to arrange your goal is to add ORDER BY, like this:

```
List<Training_Certification__c> trainCertRecords = 
    [SELECT Id, Name, Course_Level__c, Course_Description__c 
     FROM Training_Certification__c
     ORDER BY Name ASC];
```

Actual field values, object names, and variables may differ, but this should be enough to get you started.

You'll want to read more on the [SOQL SELECT Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm) to make sure you get ORDER BY in the right part of the query; it goes after FROM, WHERE, WITH, GROUP BY and HAVING, but before LIMIT, OFFSET, or the FOR VIEW/REFERENCE/UPDATE, etc. clauses.

Comment: Here is what my code looks like<apex:page standardController="Training_Certification__c" recordSetVar="Training_Certification__c" sidebar="false">
<h1> Welcome to Guidance Software's Sales Training and Certification Courses </h1>
<apex:pageBlock title="Guidance Software Sales Training and Certification Videos">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Training_Certification__c}" var="a">
<apex:column value="{!a.Course_Code_v2__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.Course_Level__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.Course_Description__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>